# How to uninstall Snapz Pro and all its cruft

Tags: macos

Title pretty much says it all.

I've used, and loved, Snapz Pro for many years but it's finally broken to the point I have to give it up. Unfortunately, Ambrosia Software doesn't seem to be supporting it anymore and there's no published uninstall app or procedure.

Snapz Pro is *not* one of my login apps and I've deleted every agent, daemon, and system file I can find with the name "Snapz" or "Ambrosia". But the next time I start up, Snapz Pro launches again, so **something** is still installed that's starting it up.

I'm pretty sure if I simply delete the Snapz Pro app at that point it will go away, but I'd really like to find out what's still launching it every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can search your system with Spotlight to find all associated files (binaries, plist files, etc) to try and remove it.

I've also used AppCleaner in the past which does that for you (I'm not affiliated with them at all, I've just used the app and it worked well for me)
https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/

Make sure your trash is empty as well after deleting those files you *did* find.

Be aware that the app may go by other names as well. You can open up Activity Monitor when the app starts and find the name of the binary it is actually running as.

We can search for the running binary in the Terminal.
Type `ps x | grep [s]nap` to try and locate the running app. It should return an output that looks something like this if it found it:

```
15828 ?        Sl     0:00 snapz
```

Note how the first letter in the grep expression has brackets around it. Make sure the first character of whatever you are searching for is in those square brackets so that you don't end up getting results for yourself ([more info here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74185/how-can-i-prevent-grep-from-showing-up-in-ps-results?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa))

So take note of the PID (15828 in this case)

then run this, replacing PID-FOUND-ABOVE with the PID number:
`lsof -p PID-FOUND-ABOVE | awk '$4 == "txt" { print $9 }'`

Assuming you picked the right PID from the `ps` command we ran, that should return *where* the running Snapz Pro app is that you can't seem to find. If you have confirmed that what it returned is, in fact, your app then just go ahead and delete it!

Comment: Thanks, Michael, but as I said I've already done that. There are still mystery components installed somewhere.

Comment: Hi @JamesBucanek - right, totally get that. So my suggestion about the app going by other names and using Activity Monitor is key here too. If the Activity Monitor suggestion wasn't helpful, we can do this in the terminal. I've updated my answer to reflect that. Also, make sure your macOS trash has been emptied of any binaries you _did_ find.

Comment: I appreciate your enthusiasm, Michael, but that's not the issue. I know what binary is getting started. I want to know what executable/service is launching it.

Comment: @JamesBucanek I mean if you remove the binary that is getting started, you won't have this app starting anymore. If you want to figure out what is starting the binary, a process tree might help. Something like `pstree`. [More ideas here on this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/11770/101013)

Comment: LOL, Snapz Pro was launching itself. The parent process of Snapz was `launchd`, which didn't really tell me much. I finally found a `com.ambrosiasw.SnapzLoginHelper` job registered with `launchd`, but getting the job details wouldn't give me a path to the executable, only that it was "submitted by otherbsd". It turns out, otherbsd gets its marching orders from `loginitemregisterd` which searches for login apps imbedded inside other apps, which is exactly what's inside the `Snapz Pro` application bundle. Trashed the app and it went away. *Whew* Thanks for all the help!